# A fake proof of pull-back of an ample divisor is ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi: X \to Y$ be a morphism between projective varieties and $H$ be an ample divisor on $Y$. I want to "show" $\pi^*H$ is ample on $X$ by the following argument:

Let $N_1(X)_\mathbb{R},N_1(Y)_\mathbb{R}$ be vector spaces of 1-cycles module numerical equivalence, and let $NE(X),NE(Y)$ be the cones of effective 1-cycles in $N_1(X)_\mathbb{R},N_1(Y)_\mathbb{R}$ with $\overline{NE(X)},\overline{NE(Y)}$ being their closures.

Then we have a continuous map

> $\pi_*:  N_1(X)_\mathbb{R} \to N_1(Y)_\mathbb{R}$
>   defined by $[C] \mapsto [\pi_* C]$.

Where if $C$ is an irreducible curve, then $\pi_* C$ is defined to be $\deg(\pi)\pi(C)$ when $\pi$ does not contract $C$, and $0$ otherwise.

$\pi_*$ induces a continuous map

> $\pi_*: \overline{NE(X)} \to \overline{NE(Y)}$.

Kleiman's criterion shows: $H $ is ample $\iff$ $\forall ~C' \in \overline{NE(Y)}, H\cdot C'>0$ .

Let $C \in \overline{NE(X)}$, and $C_i \to C$. Then by projection formula, we have

> $\pi^* H \cdot C_i = H \cdot \pi_* C_i > 0$, and hence $\pi^* H \cdot C>0$.

By  Kleiman's criterion again, $\pi^*H$ is an ample divisor.

I know ampleness does not behave quite well under pull back, one need some extra condition (e.g. finite morphism) to make sure $\pi^*H$ preserve ampleness. There must be something wrong in the above argument, and I will be very appreciated if someone can point it to me!!

Comment: Suppose $\pi$ contracts $C_i$, then $\pi^*H\cdot C_i=H\cdot [0]=0$ and is not strictly positive. Note that a condition like finite will prevent any of the $C_i$ from being contracted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see where I am wrong.

Comment: A small mistake: your statement of Kleiman's criterion should be: $H$ is ample $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall C'\in \overline{NE(Y)}-\{0\}$, $H\cdot C'>0$.

Comment: You are absolutely right!!